# programatically create/manipulate visio drawing in vsdx file

Tags: c#, vba, visio

I need to deploy a visio visualization programmatically. For the moment I just need to add sticky notes with the attributes: size, position, color, text on it and text alignment, but the solution should be expandable with further shapes in the future. The information about the shapes is stored in google cloud firestore database. I am quite open for any kind of solutions and code language, but if possible it would be great to run google cloud functions, which supports Node.js, Python, and Go, but I also read about supporting .NET, moreover it should be open source if possible.
I am totally not an experienced code developer, thus it would be great if you could provide some code examples. That's what I actually miss in all the documentation I found.

As far as I researched the Visio 2016 SDK would be interesting in this case. But I didn't find close examples as I need. F.e. [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/how-to-manipulate-the-visio-file-format-programmatically) shows how to replace text in a shape, or [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-add-shapes-to-a-visio-document?view=vs-2019) shows how to add a rectangular shape. But the explanation is rare...
I analyzed the visio file itself with master..XML, page..XML etc., but the amount of values is confusing. And this leads me to the question how the SDK will handle this? How can I define master shapes, how do I format them?

Another option would be the Apose.Diagram API, but I am not shure if the sticky note is supported. An example is provided [here](https://docs.aspose.com/display/diagramjava/Add%2C+Retrieve%2C+Copy+and+Read+Visio+Shape+Data). Unfortunately it's commercial, but if there is no other option i would go for it.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: " to deploy a visio visualization programmatically". Do you mean you want to write some code to create a Visio document?

Comment: yes exactly. The aim is to deploy a visio file with drawing/shapes on it based on information about shapes in a database (I just changed the title from ..visio file > ...visio drawing ;)

Comment: As it stands, your question is too broad for a good Stack Overflow response. Why don't you give it a shot and let us know when you get stuck on a specific error?

Answer (score 0):

just as an information about the actual state: i kind of "solved it" with manually manipulating the vsdx. the vsdx is just a compressed zip-file with ending .vsdx. If you rename it to .zip, you will see many xml-files. the file page1.xml is the one important if you just need to place simple shapes without relations to each other.
In the page1.xml there are xml-parts named as , just manipulate & multiplicate these parts.
I didnt try the sdk yet, or an third-party solution like apose.diagram, but for the actual use case of visualizing objects in form of a rectangle its good enough